# How to conditionally set required attribute when element is not hidden

Tags: javascript, html, laravel

Whenever I place a `$(".Othertext").attr('required', '');` before the show call for the element it shows the textbox regardless of the button condition. Is there any way to make it so that the textbox is required and shown when the Other button is clicked?

```
<label class="mdl-radio mdl-js-radio mdl-js-ripple-effect" for="DF4">
     <input type="radio" id="DF4" class="mdl-radio__button" name="DF" value="4">
     <span class="mdl-radio__label">Other - please describe in detail</span>
</label>

<div class="Othertext">
    <div class="mdl-textfield mdl-js-textfield mdl-textfield--floating-label">
         <input class="mdl-textfield__input" type="text" id="othertext">
         <span class="mdl-textfield__label">Describe...</span>
    </div>
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
      $(".Othertext").hide();
      $('input[type=radio][name=DF]').change(function() {
      if($(this).val() == 4)
          $(".Othertext").show();
      else
          $(".Othertext").hide();
      });
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works fine for me:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#othertext").hide();
  $('input[type=radio][name=DF]').change(function() {
    if($(this).val() == 4) {
        $("#othertext").show();
        $("#othertext").attr('required', '');
    }            
    else {
        $("#othertext").hide();
        $("#othertext").removeAttr('required', '');
    }
  });
});
```

However remember to use brackets when you have more then 1 line in the if statement.

Comment: If you do not remove the required attribute in the else conditional, you can run into issues on form submit with the inability to target an element that is hidden. Also you should prefer `.prop()` and `.removeProp` over `.attr` and `.removeAttr` for this particular task.

Comment: I was forgetting the damn brackets...thanks! @Ohgodwhy why do those make a better fit?

Comment: @epictaco24 Some time ago, jQuery added the `.prop()` and `.removeProp()` features to the spec. They deprecated, and then shortly thereafter, removed `.attr()` and `.removeAttr()`. Community outcry began due to re-writes of code. Instead, they re-wrote the spec, dictating the `attributes`. Saving you too much bore, default properties such as `name`, `value`, `required`, etc, should be accessed through `.prop()` whereas attributes, such as `title`, `content`, and `data-` attributes should be accessed through `.attr()`. Similarly, `removeProp` and `removeAttr` should follow similar guidelines.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy, you were right about the else statement. But give me a link to that 'too much bore', I am actually curious.

Comment: @epictao, Funny thing, I forgot the brackets myself too in the edit. That's why I always use the brackets myself, without exceptions.